# Jupyter notebook, ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:

Tags: pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I have a problem when I try to import pandas in Jupyter notebook. The error occurs only when I import pandas in a .ipynb file, in fact in a .py file it works.

[image]

This is the error:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you read the "advice on how to solve this issue?" Did you check your python and numpy versions? Do you have numpy installed? How did you install pandas: conda or pip?

Comment: @It_is_Chris I've installed initially numpy with pip, but it doesn't work with conda either.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed / do you have virtual environments? Are you installing the numpy package in the correct environment?

Comment: I created a new virtual environment using conda and I tried to install all libraries using the conda command and never pip and seems working now. Is there any problems  installing libraries using both pip and conda command?

Comment: No, some packages can only be installed with pip. The issue is if you have multiple versions of python installed (especially on windows). This can cause issues if you install packages in the terminal and the anaconda prompt. They will most likely point to two different installations of python.

Answer (score 0):

Check which jupyter-notebook you are using(environment specific),

1. Deactivate your current virtualenv
   using `deactivate`
2. Do `pip uninstall jupyter-notebook`
3. Activate your virtualenv
   then run jupyter-notebook

This will probably solve your issue